# .htaccess url rewriting without collision

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got the following code in my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1
```

The above code works fine like this, `http://domain.com/username` instead of `http://domain.com/profile.php?username=username`

I need a similar one but with a fake string like this

```
http://domain.com/gallery/username
```

The file is at http://domain.com/gallery.php

How do I achieve this without colliding with profile code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost the same:

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ gallery.php?username=$1
```

If you also would allow other non ascii nicknames you should replace `([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)` by `([^\/]+)`.

Just as a hint you can remove the first rule if you add a questionmark after the slash that makes the slash optional.

Comment: How do I disallow url like http://domain.com/username#   or other specials characters?

Comment: The # is in general not sent to the server if it is not special encoded. If the # is correctly urlencoded it would break nothing. Querrystings are always more complex but I guess it will be appended with the flag `[qsa]`. [RTFM reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa). :)